# Failed to Compile error - Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs

**This is a React app - Here is my code:**
NewsContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'

export const NewsContext = createContext()

export const NewsContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const apikey = "e25c25eb946e48779021963c288ce5cc";

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(
                'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2021-06-21&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=${apiKey}'
            )
            .then(response => setData(response.data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }, [data]);

    return (
        <NewsContextProvider props={data}>
            {props.children}
        </NewsContextProvider>,;
    );
};
```

But when I run it I get this error:
[Copy of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPH70.png)

./src/NewsContext.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users\HP\Documents\GitHub\newsfinder-app\src\NewsContext.js: Unexpected token (22:31)

20 |         
21 |             {props.children}

> 22 |         ,;
> |                                ^
> 23 |     );
> 24 | };

Comment: Get rid of the `,;` at the end of line 22

Comment: When I do that I get a whole bunch of new errors -

Comment: "a whole bunch of new errors" is not a helpful description of your problem.

Comment: Sorry - the list was really long I couldnt even copy it.  I am new to this so appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```js
import React, {createContext, useEffect, useState} from "react"
import axios from "axios"

export const NewsContext = createContext()

export const NewsContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const apikey = "e25c25eb946e48779021963c288ce5cc"

  const apiUrl = `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2021-06-21&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=${apikey}`

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        apiUrl
      )
      .then(response => setData(response.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }, [data, apiUrl])

  return (
    <NewsContextProvider props={data}>
      {props.children}
    </NewsContextProvider>
  )
}
```

and in the index.js just do:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {NewsContextProvider} from "./NewContextProvider"

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <NewsContextProvider>
      <App />
    </NewsContextProvider>

  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: I copied your code and now I get this error:   ./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './NewContextProvider' in 'C:\Users\HP\Documents\GitHub\newsfinder-app\src'

Comment: you need to update the path for the NewContextProvider. What is the path?

Comment: That is the path, i didnt change it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your code is, there are two errors

> Remove the `,;` from `return` block

> And use **backticks** instead of **single quotation**. It's called [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

> And the Last one is Passing the `data` in array in `useEffect`, it'll cause an infinite loop when the component will render, just pass an empty array, it means it will run only once when the component mounts

```
  axios
  .get(
    `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2021-06- 
     21&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=${apiKey}`) 
// should be backticks
  .then(response => setData(response.data))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

And In useEffect

```
const apiRequest = () =>{
 const apikey = "e25c25eb946e48779021963c288ce5cc";
        axios
            .get(
                `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2021-06-21&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=${apiKey}`
            )
            .then(response => setData(response.data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
useEffect(() => {
        apiRequest();
    }, []); // you should not pass data, 
// as it will cause an infinitie loop in the useEffect, just pass empty array to avoid the loop
```

So the Code will look like

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'

export const NewsContext = createContext()

export const NewsContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    //const apikey = "e25c25eb946e48779021963c288ce5cc";

    const apiRequest = () =>{
        const apikey = "e25c25eb946e48779021963c288ce5cc";
        axios
            .get(
                `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2021-06-21&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=${apiKey}`
            )
            .then(response => setData(response.data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
     }

     useEffect(() => {
        apiRequest();
    }, []);

    return (
        <NewsContextProvider props={data}>
            {props.children}
        </NewsContextProvider>
    );
};
```

Comment: so this should have backticks? 'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2021-06-21&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=${apiKey}'

Comment: So I did the above actions and now I get:    src\NewsContext.js
  Line 12:104:  'apiKey' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: I appreciate all the help - I am new to all of this

Comment: Updated my answer, according to your request. @tbrev

Comment: I feel so dumb, im sorry - can you show me what the whole code would be? Im not sure where to insert this and what to replace?

Comment: Thank you.  I still get the same errors, unfortunately. ./src/NewsContext.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users\HP\Documents\GitHub\newsfinder-app\src\NewsContext.js: Unexpected token (27:31)

  25 |         <NewsContextProvider props={data}>
  26 |             {props.children}
> 27 |         </NewsContextProvider>,;

Comment: And if I delete the ,: i get the other error: Line 14:104:  'apiKey' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: share a sandbox link, it's really hard for me to debug and give me a correct solution.

Comment: I think you're getting the wrong idea about Provider Pattern here. Are you using Provider pattern?